# Return multiple mySQL rows that have one common column value, place into separate arrays...?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok. I looked all over the site, and I keep coming close, but no cigar... Everyone else's "multiple row return" questions all have one thing in common that mine doesn't... They are rows that have different values in the column that is being used for the query...
I have a DB that is returning event date information to a PHP calendar... The DB is set up, and I have the calendar set up, and queries go alright... but only if there's only one event on the specified day... If there are 2 events for that date in the DB, the query only returns the first event...
I need to know how to query:

`SELECT * FROM CraftShows WHERE Date = $date`

...and then (say there are 2 rows returned from that query...) have the two rows that are returned put into SEPARATE variables, within another array for easy access...

preferably: first row goes into `$show[0]` and second goes into `$show[1]`...

so that afterward, i can write a while loop in my calendar PHP file that iterates through the array, echoing the rows into a `<TD>` element...

I wish I had a snippet of what i had, but I jumbled it all up, and it's completely screwed. I'll post this while I try again, and then update this post with my second attempt... I hope this was clear enough... Thanks for any help in advance. Cheers!

-Andrew

addendum:

here's the code that works, but only returns the first event should there be more than one with the matching `$showdate` in the DB...

`while ( $day_num <= $days_in_month ) {`

`$showdate = $year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day_num;`

`$showdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM CraftShows WHERE Date = '$showdate'");`

`$row = mysql_fetch_array($showdata);`

`echo "<td id = 'caldata' height=240px width=120px valign = 'top'> $day_num <br> $row[0]`

`<br> $row[1] <br> $row[3] </td>";`

`$day_num++;`

`$day_count++;`

`if ($day_count > 7) {
echo "</tr><tr>";
$day_count = 1;
}`

`}`

Comment: There is no reason why that query should only return one record if there are multiple records with `Date = $date`. The question is whether you know how to loop through the result set. If you do, then the answer to this question should be readily apparently, as you can you add each record as an array element with each loop iteration. Without seeing code, it is impossible to know where you have gone wrong.

Comment: And how are you currently assigning the result rows? Have you tried `$results[] = $row` or `$results[$row['Date']][] = $row` ?

Comment: wow! you guys respond quicker than i can think! let me try to implement mario's suggestion(s), and see what i can come up with...

Comment: Answered by Danielx2010... Please upvote his answer, as I cannot. Thanks for all your help guys.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using PHP, you might want something like:

```
$dbh = Database::connect();
$query = "SELECT * FROM CraftShows WHERE Date = ?";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute(array($date));    
for($i=0 ; $i<$sth->rowCount() ; $i++){
    $show[$i] = $sth->fetch();
}
return $show;
```

OBS: if your table `CraftShows` has, for instance, the columns `a`, `b` and `c`, then each element of `$show` will be an array with 3 elements (`a`, `b` and `c`).
For exeple, `$show[2]["b"]` will contain the field `b` for the third row fetched in the query.

OBS2: `Database` is supposed to be the PHP class that connects with your database. Something like:

```
class Database {

    public static function connect() {
        $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=name_here;host=host_here';
        $user = 'username_here';
        $password = 'password_here';

        try {
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection Failed : ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit(0);
        }
        return $dbh;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
With your code update, you may want to try this:

```
   $return = array();
   $i=0;
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($showdata)) {
       $return[$i] = $row;
       $i++;
   }
```

The result will be in `$return`

Comment: Could you please explain why you downvoted this answer? I use this code all the time and it works perfectly for the purpose of the question asked.

Comment: YES! That's how you loop through the set! AWESOME! Thank you so much... Your first code was WWAAAAYYY over my head, for a third day programmer... But thank you for re-posting. You made my day! *upvote*

Comment: Crap... Well, guess I'll upvote it when I get the street cred. Thanks again though!

Comment: @AndrewMott Glad it helped :D If it worked, you can accept the anwser by clicking on the "check" symbol on the left of my answer. Have a nice day